# How do I link the CrossHairTool in bokeh over several plots?

Tags: python, bokeh

When moving the crosshair (dimensions=width) in one plot I want to see the same position in the other plot(s). My plots share the same x-axis.

Here is the plot setup and an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, output_file, save
from bokeh.models import Span, CrosshairTool, HoverTool, ResetTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool
from datetime import datetime



def timeline_figure(title=None, x_range=None, y_range=None):

    # TODO: align x-axis

    # TOOLS = "resize,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,box_select,lasso_select,save"
    # TOOLS = "resize,crosshair,xpan,xwheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
    TOOLS = [CrosshairTool(dimensions=['height']),
             PanTool(dimensions=['width']),
             HoverTool(tooltips=[("Dato", "@Date")]),
             WheelZoomTool(dimensions=['width']),
             ResetTool()]

    # Setting up the bokeh figure
    fig = figure(width=800, height=250, title=title, x_axis_type="datetime",
                 x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, tools=TOOLS)

    # make the outline "invisible"
    fig.outline_line_color = 'white'

    # change just some things about the x-grid
    fig.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    # change just some things about the y-grid

    fig.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None

    year = 2016
    dec = Span(location=datetime(year-1, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000,
                    dimension='height', line_color='grey', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
    jan = Span(location=datetime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000,
               dimension='height', line_color='grey', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
    feb = Span(location=datetime(year, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000,
               dimension='height', line_color='grey', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
    mar = Span(location=datetime(year, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000,
               dimension='height', line_color='grey', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
    apr = Span(location=datetime(year, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000,
               dimension='height', line_color='grey', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
    may = Span(location=datetime(year, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000,
               dimension='height', line_color='grey', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)

    fig.renderers.extend([dec, jan, feb, mar, apr, may])

    return fig


def usage():
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import timedelta
    from bokeh.io import gridplot

    output_file("test.html", mode="cdn")

    d_start = datetime(2016, 6, 1)
    d_step = timedelta(days=1)

    t = [d_start + (i * d_step) for i in range(0, 12)]
    s1 = np.random. randint(2, 10, 12)
    s2 = np.random.randint(2, 10, 12)
    source = ColumnDataSource({'t': t, 's1': s1, 's2': s2})

    p1 = timeline_figure()
    p1.triangle(x='t', y='s1', source=source, size=10, color="blue")
    p2 = timeline_figure()
    p2.square(x='t', y='s2', source=source, size=10, color="red")

    p = gridplot([[p1], [p2]])
    save(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    usage()
```

Grateful for any advice.

Karsten

Answer (score 16):

As of bokeh v2.2.1 the solution is simplified. I am not sure whether it was already possible like this in previous versions. Here an example for sharing crosshair for both dimensions between 9 plots in a gridplot in bokeh v2.2.1:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import CrosshairTool

plots = [figure() for i in range(6)]
[plot.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10)) for plot in plots]
crosshair = CrosshairTool(dimensions="both")
for plot in plots:
    plot.add_tools(crosshair)

show(gridplot(children=[plot for plot in plots], ncols=3))
```

Comment: thanks for this. saved me so much time going through older more complicated answers

Comment: Thanks, but this one is showing on y-axis too, and same crosshair is being shown on all plots. I mean, horizontal line is shown on other plots as well.

Comment: Is there a way to change the crosshair color?

Answer (score 11):

Bokeh currently has no built in support for this. I figured out how to do this using javascript callbacks. The following function works for two vertically aligned plots on Bokeh 0.13:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, CrosshairTool

def add_vlinked_crosshairs(fig1, fig2):
    cross1 = CrosshairTool()
    cross2 = CrosshairTool()
    fig1.add_tools(cross1)
    fig2.add_tools(cross2)
    js_move = '''
        if(cb_obj.x >= fig.x_range.start && cb_obj.x <= fig.x_range.end &&
           cb_obj.y >= fig.y_range.start && cb_obj.y <= fig.y_range.end)
        {
            cross.spans.height.computed_location = cb_obj.sx
        }
        else
        {
            cross.spans.height.computed_location = null
        }
    '''
    js_leave = 'cross.spans.height.computed_location = null'
    args = {'cross': cross2, 'fig': fig1}
    fig1.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_move))
    fig1.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_leave))
    args = {'cross': cross1, 'fig': fig2}
    fig2.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_move))
    fig2.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_leave))
```

The idea is to add a mouse move callback to each plot which triggers the vertical part of the crosshair on the other plot to be drawn. This is done by updating the `spans.height.computed_location` member of the crosshair with the screen position provided by the mouse callback (`cb_obj.sx`).

The mouse move event fires on the entire area of the plot, including axes, borders etc. Checks are added to make sure the mouse is inside the data space (`cb_obj.x` and `cb_obj.y` are axis coordinates) and the line is removed if it is not. A `mouseleave` event was also added since a fast move outside of the plot may not fire an event on the border area.

This works if the plots are vertically aligned. For horizontal alignment (as per the OP) just change `cross.spans.height.computed_location` -> `cross.spans.width.computed_location` and `cb_obj.sx` -> `cb_obj.sy`.

This only works if the plots are the same size, further checks will be necessary if they are not.

Answer (score 5):

Marged solution (updated for Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, CrosshairTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, output_file, save, show
from bokeh.models import Span, CrosshairTool, HoverTool, ResetTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
import time

def add_vlinked_crosshairs(fig1, fig2):
    js_move = '''if(cb_obj.x >= fig.x_range.start && cb_obj.x <= fig.x_range.end && cb_obj.y >= fig.y_range.start && cb_obj.y <= fig.y_range.end)
                    { cross.spans.height.computed_location = cb_obj.sx }
                 else 
                    { cross.spans.height.computed_location = null }'''
    js_leave = 'cross.spans.height.computed_location = null'

    cross1 = CrosshairTool()
    cross2 = CrosshairTool()
    fig1.add_tools(cross1)
    fig2.add_tools(cross2)
    args = {'cross': cross2, 'fig': fig1}
    fig1.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args = args, code = js_move))
    fig1.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args = args, code = js_leave))
    args = {'cross': cross1, 'fig': fig2}
    fig2.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args = args, code = js_move))
    fig2.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args = args, code = js_leave))

def to_seconds(date):
    return time.mktime(date.timetuple())

def timeline_figure(title = None, x_range = None, y_range = None):

    TOOLS = [CrosshairTool(dimensions = 'height'), PanTool(dimensions = 'width'), HoverTool(tooltips = [("Date", "@t")]), WheelZoomTool(dimensions = 'width'), ResetTool()]

    fig = figure(width = 800, height = 250, title = title, x_axis_type = "datetime", x_range = x_range, y_range = y_range, tools = TOOLS)
    fig.outline_line_color = 'white'
    fig.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None

    year = 2016
    dec = Span(location = to_seconds(datetime(year - 1, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
    jan = Span(location = to_seconds(datetime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
    feb = Span(location = to_seconds(datetime(year, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
    mar = Span(location = to_seconds(datetime(year, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
    apr = Span(location = to_seconds(datetime(year, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
    may = Span(location = to_seconds(datetime(year, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0)))

    fig.renderers.extend([dec, jan, feb, mar, apr, may])

    return fig

def usage():
    output_file("test_linked_crosshair.html", mode = "cdn")

    d_start = datetime(2016, 6, 1)
    d_step = timedelta(days = 1)

    t = [d_start + (i * d_step) for i in range(0, 12)]
    s1 = np.random. randint(2, 10, 12)
    s2 = np.random.randint(2, 10, 12)
    source = ColumnDataSource({'t': t, 's1': s1, 's2': s2})

    p1 = timeline_figure()
    p1.triangle(x = 't', y = 's1', source = source, size = 10, color = "blue")
    p2 = timeline_figure(x_range = p1.x_range)
    p2.square(x = 't', y = 's2', source = source, size = 10, color = "red")

    add_vlinked_crosshairs(p1, p2)

    p = gridplot([[p1], [p2]])
    show(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    usage()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

More compact example for arbitrary number of plots and for both CrossHair dimensions (updated for Bokeh v1.0.4):

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, CrosshairTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import numpy as np

def addLinkedCrosshairs(plots):
    js_move = '''   start = fig.x_range.start, end = fig.x_range.end
                    if(cb_obj.x>=start && cb_obj.x<=end && cb_obj.y>=start && cb_obj.y<=end)
                        { cross.spans.height.computed_location=cb_obj.sx }
                    else { cross.spans.height.computed_location = null }
                    if(cb_obj.y>=start && cb_obj.y<=end && cb_obj.x>=start && cb_obj.x<=end)
                        { cross.spans.width.computed_location=cb_obj.sy  }
                    else { cross.spans.width.computed_location=null }'''
    js_leave = '''cross.spans.height.computed_location=null; cross.spans.width.computed_location=null'''

    figures = plots[:]
    for plot in plots:
        crosshair = CrosshairTool(dimensions = 'both')
        plot.add_tools(crosshair)
        for figure in figures:
            if figure != plot:
                args = {'cross': crosshair, 'fig': figure}
                figure.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args = args, code = js_move))
                figure.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args = args, code = js_leave))

plots = [figure(plot_width = 200, plot_height = 200, tools = '') for i in range(9)]
[plot.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10)) for plot in plots]
addLinkedCrosshairs(plots)
show(gridplot(children = [plot for plot in plots], ncols = 3))
```

To reduce to just one dimension (vertical or horizontal) remove the corresponding "if / else" part of the callback

Result:

[image]

Comment: For me this solution works with the horizontal line being flipped. For example, assume the center to be 0. While in one plot the horizontal line is in 50, in the other it is in -50.

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest Bokeh version. The previous code was for Bokeh v0.12.6. Now I updated the code for v1.0.4 and it works fine.

Comment: It is very unprofessional voting down while the answer clearly states the solution is for Bokeh v0.12.6 and you are using different version. All my answers include Bokeh version for which it applies

Comment: How to keep the level equal according to the axis not only relative in the DOM/subplot?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the people who liked Graeme's solution just as I did, but need to apply it to more than two figures just as I did:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, CrosshairTool

def add_vlinked_crosshairs(figs):
    js_leave = ''
    js_move = 'if(cb_obj.x >= fig.x_range.start && cb_obj.x <= fig.x_range.end &&\n'
    js_move += 'cb_obj.y >= fig.y_range.start && cb_obj.y <= fig.y_range.end){\n'
    for i in range(len(figs)-1):
        js_move += '\t\t\tother%d.spans.height.computed_location = cb_obj.sx\n' % i
    js_move += '}else{\n'
    for i in range(len(figs)-1):
        js_move += '\t\t\tother%d.spans.height.computed_location = null\n' % i
        js_leave += '\t\t\tother%d.spans.height.computed_location = null\n' % i
    js_move += '}'
    crosses = [CrosshairTool() for fig in figs]
    for i, fig in enumerate(figs):
        fig.add_tools(crosses[i])
        args = {'fig': fig}
        k = 0
        for j in range(len(figs)):
            if i != j:
                args['other%d'%k] = crosses[j]
                k += 1
        fig.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_move))
        fig.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_leave))
```

[image: crosshair on bchusdt plot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution for bokeh 3.1.1 and is based on the [linked_crosshair example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/interaction/linking/linked_crosshair.html) from the offical documentation.

This example also shows how to change the color and the style of the cross hairs.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import CrosshairTool, Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

width = Span(dimension="width", line_dash="dashed", line_width=2, line_color='magenta')
height = Span(dimension="height", line_dash="dotted", line_width=2, line_color='orange')

crosshair = CrosshairTool(overlay=[width, height])

children = []
for i in range(6):
    p = figure(width=200,height=200)
    p.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10))
    p.add_tools(crosshair)
    children.append(p)

show(gridplot(children=children, ncols=3))
```

[image: linked crosshair]

### Comment

It looks like the default `CrosshairTool` with `overlay='auto'` is not sufficant to create a linked cross hair tool anymore.

I quote from a comment in the git hub discussion in [#13180](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/13180#issuecomment-1580267483):

> The difference in behavior between 2.x and 3.x is that previously auto overlays were stored in tool's model and thus shared between views, whereas now they are stored in tool models' view and thus private. The linked behavior was meant to be achieved by sharing of overlays and not tools.