# Can't get CrossHairTool in Bokeh to be linked over several plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I've studied the post:

"How do I link the CrossHairTool in bokeh over several plots?" (See [How do I link the CrossHairTool in bokeh over several plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965669/how-do-i-link-the-crosshairtool-in-bokeh-over-several-plots).

I used the function written by **Hamid Fadishei** on June 2020 within this post but cannot manage to get the CrossHairTool to correctly display over several plots.

In my implementation, the crosshair displays only within the plot hovered over. I am currently using Bokeh version **2.1.1** with Python Anaconda version **3.7.6** using the Python extension in VSCode version 1.48. I am not familiar with Javascript, so any help to debug my code to correctly display the crosshair across the two plots will be welcomed.

My code:

```
# Importing libraries:
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, CrosshairTool, ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

# Function wrote by Hamid Fadishei to enable a linked crosshair within gridplot:
def add_vlinked_crosshairs(figs):
    js_leave = ''
    js_move = 'if(cb_obj.x >= fig.x_range.start && cb_obj.x <= fig.x_range.end &&\n'
    js_move += 'cb_obj.y >= fig.y_range.start && cb_obj.y <= fig.y_range.end){\n'
    for i in range(len(figs)-1):
        js_move += '\t\t\tother%d.spans.height.computed_location = cb_obj.sx\n' % i
    js_move += '}else{\n'
    for i in range(len(figs)-1):
        js_move += '\t\t\tother%d.spans.height.computed_location = null\n' % i
        js_leave += '\t\t\tother%d.spans.height.computed_location = null\n' % i
    js_move += '}'
    crosses = [CrosshairTool() for fig in figs]
    for i, fig in enumerate(figs):
        fig.add_tools(crosses[i])
        args = {'fig': fig}
        k = 0
        for j in range(len(figs)):
            if i != j:
                args['other%d'%k] = crosses[j]
                k += 1
        fig.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_move))
        fig.js_on_event('mouseleave', CustomJS(args=args, code=js_leave))

# Create dataframe consisting of 5 random numbers within column A and B as a function of an arbitrary time range:
startDate = datetime(2020,5,1)
timeStep = timedelta(minutes = 5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [startDate  + (i * timeStep) for i in range(5)],
    "A": [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(5)],
    "B": [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(5)]})

# Generate output file as html file:
output_file("test_linked_crosshair.html", title='Results')
# Define selection tools within gridplot:
select_tools = ["xpan", "xwheel_zoom", "box_zoom", "reset", "save"]

sample = ColumnDataSource(df)

# Define figures:
fig_1 = figure(plot_height=250,
             plot_width=800,
             x_axis_type="datetime",
             x_axis_label='Time',
             y_axis_label='A',
             toolbar_location='right',
             tools=select_tools)

fig_1.line(x='Date', y='A',
          source=sample,
          color='blue',
          line_width=1)

fig_2 = figure(plot_height=250,
             plot_width=800,
             x_range=fig_1.x_range,
             x_axis_type="datetime",
             x_axis_label='Time',
             y_axis_label='B',
             toolbar_location='right',
             tools=select_tools)

fig_2.line(x='Date', y='B',
          source=sample,
          color='red',
          line_width=1)

# Define hover tool for showing timestep and value of crosshair on graph:
fig_1.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('','@Date{%F,%H:%M}'),
                                   ('','@A{0.00 a}')],
                         formatters={'@Date':'datetime'},mode='vline'))

fig_2.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('','@Date{%F,%H:%M}'),
                                   ('','@B{0.00 a}')],
                         formatters={'@Date':'datetime'},mode='vline'))

# Calling function to enable linked crosshairs within gridplot:
add_vlinked_crosshairs([fig_1, fig_2])
# Generate gridplot:
p = gridplot([[fig_1], [fig_2]])
show(p)
```

[myGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa6gm.jpg)`enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a solution that works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812308/1090455) as of Bokeh 2.2.1: Just use the *same crosshair tool object* for all the plots that need it linked. Like so:

```py
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import CrosshairTool

plots = [figure() for i in range(6)]
[plot.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10)) for plot in plots]

linked_crosshair = CrosshairTool(dimensions="both")

for plot in plots:
    plot.add_tools(linked_crosshair)

show(gridplot(children=[plot for plot in plots], ncols=3))
```